# Pasar parámetros a jqGrid

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, variables, jqgrid

Tengo un jqGrid, en el cual carga los datos. Al entrar en la pagina, lo primero que me aparece es un pequeño dialogo que me pide un mes y el año. Cuando le das ha aceptar carga el dialogo. Me gustaría saber cómo puedo pasar estas variables al archivo de carga, para poder filtrar la consulta por ese mes y ese año.

Muchas gracias y un saludo.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
        <title>CTA - Cuotas</title>

        <!-- The jQuery library is a prerequisite for all jqSuite products -->
        <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../js/jquery.min.js"></script> 
        <!-- This is the Javascript file of jqGrid -->   
        <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../js/trirand/jquery.jqGrid.min.js"></script>
        <!-- This is the localization file of the grid controlling messages, labels, etc.
        <!-- We support more than 40 localizations -->
        <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../js/trirand/i18n/grid.locale-es.js"></script>
        <!-- A link to a jQuery UI ThemeRoller theme, more than 22 built-in and many more custom -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/jquery-ui.css" />
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/cuotas.css" />

        <!-- The link to the CSS that the grid needs -->
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="../css/trirand/ui.jqgrid.css" />
        <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../js/codetabs.js"></script>
        <script type="text/ecmascript" src="../js/themeswitchertool.js"></script>


        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $('.menuContainer').load('../menu.html');
            });

            function cargaForm(){
                $( function() {
                    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({id:"dialog", closeText: "" });
                } );
            }


        function load(){    

            var nMes = document.getElementById("mes").value; // formulario.mes.value;
            var nAnno = document.getElementById("anno").value; // formulario.mes.value;

            $("#dialog").dialog('close');

                jQuery("#tblCuotas").jqGrid({
                    url:'cargaCuotas.php',
                    datatype: 'json',
                    mtype: 'POST',
                    mes: nMes,
                    anno: nAnno,
                    colModel:[
                        {
                            label: 'ID Cuota',
                            name: 'idCuota',
                            index:'idCuota',
                            width: 50,
                            key: true,
                            hidden: true
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Num. Cuota',
                            name: 'NumCuota',
                            index:'NumCuota',
                            width: 50
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'id. Afiliado',
                            name: 'idAfiliado',
                            index:'idAfiliado',
                            width: 30,
                            align: 'right'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Nombre',
                            name: 'NOMBRE',
                            index:'NOMBRE',
                            width: 300
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Cuota',
                            name: 'cuota',
                            index:'cuota',
                            width: 50,
                            align: 'right'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Mes',
                            name: 'nMes',
                            index:'nMes',
                            width: 30,
                            align: 'right'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Mes',
                            name: 'mes',
                            index:'mes',
                            width: 80
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Año',
                            name: 'anno',
                            index:'anno',
                            width: 50,
                            align: 'center'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Pagado',
                            name: 'pagado',
                            index:'pagado',
                            width: 50,
                            align: 'center'
                        },
                        {
                            label: 'Forma Pago',
                            name: 'FormaPago',
                            index:'FormaPago',
                            width: 100
                        }

                    ],  
                    loadonce: false,
                    width: window.innerWidth-20,
                    height: window.innerHeight-200,
                    pager: '#paginacion',
                    multiselect: true,
                    rowNum: 50,
                    rowList:[50,100,150],
                    sortname: 'Custom',
                    //sortorder: 'desc',
                    viewrecords: true,
                    caption: 'CUOTAS'
                });   


                jQuery("#tblCuotas").jqGrid('navGrid','#paginacion',
                    {edit:false,add:false,del:false,view:true,search:false});


        }
            function getSelectedRows() {
                var grid = $("#tblCuotas");
                var rowKey = grid.getGridParam("selrow");

                if (!rowKey)
                    alert("No ha seleccionado ninguna linea.");
                else {
                    var selectedIDs = grid.getGridParam("selarrrow");
                    var result = "";
                    for (var i = 0; i < selectedIDs.length; i++) {
                        result += selectedIDs[i] + ",";
                    }

                    alert(result);
                }                
            }

        </script>

    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>

        <script>

            function openForm() {
                $( function() {
                    $( "#dialog" ).dialog({id:"dialog", closeText: "" });
                } );
            }

        </script>

    </head>
    <body id="cuerpo" onLoad="openForm()">
        <div class="menuContainer"></div>

        <header id="submenu">
            <nav id="enlaces">
                <ul>
                     <li>
                         <a href="javascript:getSelectedRows()" >PAGAR CUOTAS SELECCIONADAS</a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                         <a href="javascript:openForm()" >LOAD</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </header>       

        <table id="tblCuotas"></table>
        <div id="paginacion"> </div>

        <div id="dialog" hidden="true" title="FILTRO DE CUOTAS">
            <div class="group">
            <table id="formulario">
                <thead>
                    <tr style="height: 35px;">
                        <th colspan="2"><label><span>Elige el mes y el año</span></label></th>
                    </tr>   
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="Mes">Mes <span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label></td>
                        <td><?php include("../recursos/mesSelect.php"); ?></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td><label for="anno">Año <span><em>(requerido)</em></span></label></td>
                        <td><input id="anno" type="number" name="anno" min="1990" max="2500" size="4" value="<?php echo date("Y"); ?>" required/></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr><td colspan="2"><button id="btn_filtrar" align="middle" class="formButtom" onClick="load()" name="generar" >FILTRAR</button></td></tr>
                </tbody>

            </table>
    </div>
        </div>

    </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo solucione. Tan sencillo como esto:

```
postData: {
                    mes: nMes,
                    anno: nAnno,
                },
```